# What is the value of $x$ in $(7+\sqrt{x}+\frac{1}{5-\sqrt{x}})$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, rational-numbers, integers

The value of $(7+\sqrt{x}+\frac{1}{5-\sqrt{x}})$ is rational for only one positive integer $x$ that is not a perfect square. What is the value of $x$?

I tried $x=1$ and i get

$$7+1+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{31}{4}$$

which is rational so im guessing $x=1$ but does anyone see how to solve this problem in a more systematic way.

Comment: If $x$ is $1$, then $x$ _is_ a perfect square.

Comment: Multiply and divide the last term by its conjugate

Answer (score 1):

The $7$ is irrelevant to the question.

$$\sqrt{x}+\frac{1}{5-\sqrt{x}}=\frac{(25-x)\sqrt{x}}{25-x}+\frac{5+\sqrt{x}}{25-x}=\frac{(26-x)\sqrt{x}+5}{25-x}$$

Do you see a value for $x$ that makes something special happen?

Comment: why is the 7 irrelevant?

Comment: If $x$ makes $7+\sqrt{x}+\frac{1}{5-\sqrt{x}}$ rational, then it also makes $\sqrt{x}+\frac{1}{5-\sqrt{x}}$ rational, since the two numbers differ by $7$, a rational number.